# Add icon to menuItem in JavaFx by CSS

Tags: javafx

I use this CSS to add icon to menuItem on JavaFX application:

```
    #mniOpen > .label{
    -fx-graphic:url(media/open.png);
}
```

It works, but one problem: my menuItem has a shortcut key (<kbd>Ctrl+O</kbd>), so in this item there are two label. In the result, the icon repeats twice for this menuItem:

[image]

How can remove the second icon (for <kbd>Ctrl+O</kbd>) ?

Answer (score 10):

Using css

```
#mniOpen > .label{
    -fx-graphic: url("media/open.png");
}
#mniOpen .accelerator-text{
    -fx-graphic: none;
}
```

Without using css

```
  Image openIcon = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("media/open.png"));
  ImageView openView = new ImageView(openIcon);
  openView.setFitWidth(15);
  openView.setFitHeight(15);
  MenuItem newMenuItem = new MenuItem("Open");
  newMenuItem.setGraphic(openView);
  newMenuItem.setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.O, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN));
```

Comment: Thank you! But I want separate the code java, design (fxgraph, fxml), style css. I don't want use everything in java code.

Comment: You have satisfied with this answer then don't forgate to accept it.